# What would be the next step after revising a manuscript?

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals, paper-submission, editors

After receiving a report on a manuscript from the referee, then the revised version must be submitted to the editor. In this step, will the revised version be sent to referee again to check that or the editor evaluate the revised version?

Comment: @Sursula Thanks for link. Actually, this link does not include an answer for my question.

Comment: Voting to close because it depends on the journal. When you submit the paper it should tell you.

Comment: @user40491 now that I look at it, the link does actually answer your question - it has this paragraph "With revised manuscripts, usually the reviewers from the previous round are selected. The editor may also decide that certain or all reviewers need not see the manuscript again, as their comments have been adequately addressed."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends. If the requested revisions are minor then the editor might be able to check the revisions themselves. Otherwise they will usually be returned to a referee, typically the ones that reviewed the original since they have read the paper before so they can review it faster than a fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if you do peer review, you are asked if you are willing to review the same paper again in case another review round is necessary. The likelyhood of having reviewers, not editors do the re-review changes depending often on how major the revisions have been. The more revisions were necessary, the more likely it is that the reviewers will do the second round - at least from my own and colleagues experience.

Comment: thank you for your answer